# Redmine - How to attach an uploaded file to a project?

Tags: redmine

I read [this document](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Files#POST), but I don't understand what `file (required): a hash of the version attributes, including:` means. What is a hash of the following parameters? I don't SHA-2 them right?

I tried several ways like writing a JSON body but the server just responses 404, no further messages.
Does anyone have an example of how to pass correct parameters? A Python example is best.

Comment: You can't just attach uploaded file to a project?!? You can attach file to issue for example, or document, or to files module, or to DMSF module. You can indeed attach to a project, but only if you have a custom field on the project of a type file...

Comment: I found the problem was the header. It requires Content-Type=application/json.